# Batch Transform output not included in Amazon SageMaker Model Monitor job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to do data quality monitoring for a Batch transform job on a very simple .csv dataset with five inputs + one target variable. Both data capture configuration and monitoring job ended without error. However, the monitoring job reported a violation on data columns (five instead of six, the baseline is a similar dataset to the input). Any clues about that?

I successfully enabled data capture for the batch transform job using this sample code:

```
transformer = Transformer(
   model_name=model_name,
   instance_count=1,
   instance_type="ml.m5.large",
   accept="text/csv",
   output_path=output_path,
   sagemaker_session=pipeline_session
)
transformer.transform(
    data=input_path,
    data_type="S3Prefix",
    content_type="text/csv",
    batch_data_capture_config=BatchDataCaptureConfig(
        destination_s3_uri= f"s3://{default_bucket}/{s3_prefix_destination}",
        generate_inference_id=True,
    ),
    split_type="Line"
)
```

It correctly gives as outputs two folders inside my S3 destination path named input/ and output/. For the data quality monitoring job I used this:

```
data_quality_model_monitor = DefaultModelMonitor(
    role=role,
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.t3.medium",
    volume_size_in_gb=50,
    max_runtime_in_seconds=3600,
)

schedule = data_quality_model_monitor.create_monitoring_schedule(
    monitor_schedule_name="schedule",
    batch_transform_input=BatchTransformInput(
        data_captured_destination_s3_uri=f"s3://{default_bucket}/{s3_prefix_destination}",
        destination="/opt/ml/processing/input",
        dataset_format=MonitoringDatasetFormat.csv(header=False),
    ),
    output_s3_uri=f's3://{default_bucket}/{s3_prefix_output}',
    statistics=f"s3://{default_bucket}/{s3_prefix_statistics}",
    constraints=f"s3://{default_bucket}/{s3_prefix_constraints}",
    schedule_cron_expression=CronExpressionGenerator.hourly(),,
    enable_cloudwatch_metrics=True,
)
```

It reports a violation on data columns (five instead of six). It seems that the monitoring job analyzes only the manifest file contained in the folder input/, missing the files inside output/. Probably there is an option to enable output/ control, but I did not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at my example notebook [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/sagemaker_model_monitor/model_monitor_batch_transform). It is most likely in your     join_source="Input"